# javascript list with content toggling acting like accordion,

Tags: javascript, list, toggle, accordion

I have a problem with pure JS list. I want the div with content (below each li) to display once the particular li is clicked. No idea how to make it work. I'm either ablo to show one "content" block or all of the at once (by adding the once that are commented now. Any help appreciated.

```
const channelList = document.getElementById("station-list");

channelList.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const target = e.target;
    if (target.matches("li")) {
        content.classList.toggle("show");
        //content2.classList.toggle("show");
        //content3.classList.toggle("show");
        //content4.classList.toggle("show");
        //content5.classList.toggle("show");
        //content6.classList.toggle("show");
    }
})
```

https://jsbin.com/valojoruhe/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/9ebxvt1u/

1. your div's must be inside a li, otherwise you'll have invalid html
2. do not use multiple id's content, content1, content2 ... it's useless, rather define a class.
3. after you've clicked on the li element find the div element (filter it out) and then apply the desired styling to it.
4. you'll need to adjust the layout for your div to be below the paragraph, for now it's on the right side but toggles appropriately.

**JS**

```
const getAllLiElements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (let i = 0; i < getAllLiElements.length; i++) {
  let element = getAllLiElements[i];
  element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const dummyText = Array.from(element.children).filter(htmlNode => htmlNode.tagName === 'DIV')[0]
    dummyText.classList.toggle('show')
  })
}
```